# Check if file-path is set in cron

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron

I am setting a cron from bash script

I want to check  if file path is set in CRON

I checked this code to create cron but this code does not help with random time

```
(crontab -l; echo "${MIN} ${HOUR} * * * /temp/filepath") | awk '!x[$0]++' | crontab -
```

Note: ${MIN} ${HOUR} are random values

This creates multiple entry for changed variable values

I want single entry created based on file path `/temp/filepath` if not there

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your exact crontab content so some of this is presumptive. The problem is related to your awk program.. I generated a "fake" crontab and simulated trying to re-add /tmp/filepath_7 .... Here is what worked for me:

```
$ for K in $(seq 0 10) ; do printf  '%2d %2d * * * %s_%d\n' "$((RANDOM % 61))" "$((RANDOM % 25))" /tmp/filepath $K ; done > $HOME/fakeCrontab.txt
$ (cat $HOME/fakeCrontab.txt ; printf  '%2d %2d * * * %s_%d\n' "$((RANDOM % 61))" "$((RANDOM % 25))" /tmp/filepath 7) | awk ' !x[$6]++ { print $0 }'
17  2 * * * /tmp/filepath_0
13 19 * * * /tmp/filepath_1
59  9 * * * /tmp/filepath_2
56 13 * * * /tmp/filepath_3
59 22 * * * /tmp/filepath_4
55 19 * * * /tmp/filepath_5
33  5 * * * /tmp/filepath_6
17 14 * * * /tmp/filepath_7
58  5 * * * /tmp/filepath_8
51 19 * * * /tmp/filepath_9
18  8 * * * /tmp/filepath_10
$
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the exact time, don't include the exact time in the string you check.

Assuming the other time fields are significant (day, month, weekday) try

```sh
crontab -l; echo "${MIN} ${HOUR} * * * /temp/filepath") |
awk '{ y = $0; sub("^[ \t ]*" $1 "[\t ]*" $2, "", y }
    !x[y]++' | crontab -
```

Depending on how thorough you want to be, you might want to perform additional whitespace normalization on the `y` value. The main beef is to use the part you care about as the index into `x`.